# BinaryTree in the standard API

Tags: java, binary-tree

My teacher told us that there is a default class in Java for binary tree. I found [this BinaryTree class](http://www.bearcave.com/software/java/misl/BinaryTree/jdoc/BinaryTree.html) and I tried to declare a `BinaryTree` object, but it didn't work.

How can I declare a `BinaryTree` using this class and which library should I include?

I wrote something like this:

```
private BinaryTree<Integer> c=new BinaryTree<Integer>();
```

but it says that `BinaryTree` cannot be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that class is certainly not the "default java one".  I guess your teacher might be talking about [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which is based on a form of [self-balancing binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

I'm not sure how old the class the link you give is but it's not using generics so it's probably Java 1.4-.  Also, it's using the default package - which is a bit of a Java no-no, suggesting it might not be production ready.  The constructor expects a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which can compare the instances that the tree will store.  For example if you want to store Integers in order, you could declare a binary tree as:

```
BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree(new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Object a, Object b){
        return ((Integer) a).intValue() - ((Integer) b).intValue();
    }
});
```

The code above declares an anonymous class which implements the `Comparator` interface.  Alternatively you can use a regular class to do the same thing:

```
MyIntegerComparator comparator = new MyIntegerComparator();    
BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree(comparator);
```

Where you have the code..

```
class MyIntegerComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object a, Object b){
        return ((Integer) a).intValue() - ((Integer) b).intValue();
    }
}
```